# Custom event on cancel the setup in wix

Tags: c#, wix, windows-installer

I am trying to add custom events on Wix installer. I succeed to add events on installation complete.
 For this I am using following code:

```
 <InstallExecuteSequence>
      <Custom Action='AcquireLaunchLock' Before='CheckForMediaPlayer'>NotInstalled</Custom>
      <Custom Action='CheckForMediaPlayer' Before='LaunchConditions'>Not Installed</Custom>
         .     
         .
         .
      <Custom Action='UpdateSyncStatus' After='CopyHelperVideos2'></Custom>
    </InstallExecuteSequence>
```

I need one custom event on Cancel also.(If user cancel the setup in between)
I am new c#. so can anybody tell me how to do this?

Comment: Add another custom action using OnExit="cancel" (or OnExit="error" if it's the case).

Comment: @Adriano can u tell me line of code?

Comment: Something like this: `<Custom Action="MyCustomAction" OnExit="cancel"></Custom>` (see http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix2/wix_xsd_custom.htm)